# How to create two tables in one db file?

Tags: java, android

I want to create two tables in one db file, but it is not working as expected.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "Bocchi.db";
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "Bocchi.db", null, 1);
    }

    public static final String TABLE_NAME1 = "users";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "breakfast";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase MyDB) {
        String table1 = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME1+"(username TEXT PRIMARY KEY, password TEXT)";
        String table2 = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME2+"(username TEXT PRIMARY KEY, energy INT)";
        MyDB.execSQL(table1);
        MyDB.execSQL(table2);
    }
```

Why am I doing like on video but it cannot create two tables. I have checked the db file, but it only has one table.

Comment: In the db file do you have table1 or table2?

Comment: it only has table1. what ever i do it only create 1 table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `onUpgrade` method like below

```java
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVer, int newVer){
    onCreate(_db);
}
```